# Horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space at CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to make TabBarView under a CustomScrollView. Here I've given the second child/widget of slivers as my DefaultTabController where I'm designing a custom TabBar and later below in the TabBarView I'm passing widgets which are defined separately.
(Removed unnecessary styling and code)

The app is unable to run due to the error defined below which I don't understand.

Code

```
class _MessageListState extends State<MessageList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text(
                  'Chats',
              ),
            ),
            messageHome()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Widget messageHome() => SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 40.0),
          child: Container(
            child: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(text: 'Messages',),
                Tab(text: 'Requests',)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        TabBarView(
          children: <Widget>[
            messageList(),
            messageList(),
          ] 
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);

Widget messageList() => ListView.builder(
  primary: false,
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount: 30,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return const ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
            'https://someimage.jpg'),
        radius: 25.0,
      ),
      title: Text(
        'Zenitsu',
      ),
      trailing: Text(
        '20.00',
      ),
      horizontalTitleGap: 10.0,
      isThreeLine: false,
      subtitle: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquam dolor quis felis facilisis. ',
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

Error

```
Viewports expand in the cross axis to fill their container and constrain their children to match their extent in the cross axis. In this case, a horizontal viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand.
The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBarView
lib\pages\message_list.dart:69
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
```

There's a lot more trailing error below this which is not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this snippet, instead of using `DefaultTabController` I am using `TabController`. If you like to use customScrollView, you can replace ListView with it. If you want more customization, you can check NestedScrollView.

```dart
class MessageList extends StatefulWidget {
  MessageList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessageList> createState() => _MessageListState();
}

class _MessageListState extends State<MessageList>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController controller;
  final tabs = const [
    Tab(
      text: 'Messages',
    ),
    Tab(
      text: 'Requests',
    )
  ];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("my app"),
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: tabs,
            controller: controller,
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TabBarView(controller: controller, children: <Widget>[
                messageList(),
                messageList(),
              ]),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget messageList() => ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 30,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return const ListTile(
            leading: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://someimage.jpg'),
              radius: 25.0,
            ),
            title: Text(
              'Zenitsu',
            ),
            trailing: Text(
              '20.00',
            ),
            horizontalTitleGap: 10.0,
            isThreeLine: false,
            subtitle: Text(
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquam dolor quis felis facilisis. ',
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          );
        },
      );
}
```